# how to dynamically populate a string array in c and why by removing unnecessary code the program doesn't work?

Tags: arrays, c, memory, memory-management

i'm trying to populate an array of strings in c using dynamic allocation, this is the code snippet

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct test_struct {
    char **names;
    int age;
} test_struct;

void add_names(char*** array, int number_of_names);

int main() {
    test_struct* ts;
    char **array;
    int number_of_names;
    
    ts = (test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(test_struct));
    
    printf("input the number of names to add: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_names);
    add_names(&array, number_of_names);
    printf("%s | %s\n", array[1], array[0]);
    return 0;
}

void add_names(char*** array, int number_of_names) {
    char *string;
    *array = malloc(sizeof(char*)*number_of_names);

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_names; i++){
        scanf("%ms", &string);
        *array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(string) + 1);
        strcpy(*array[i], string);
    }

    printf("%s | %s\n", *array[0], *array[1]);
}
```

If I try to populate it with three names I can't get over the second, and if I try to do it with two names the `printf` statement inside the function prints both names, however the one in the `main` function prints ( [name1] | (null) )
.
Also if I remove the unnecessary struct part, I have this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void add_names(char*** array, int number_of_names);

int main() {
    char **array;
    int number_of_names;
        
    printf("input the number of names to add: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_names);
    add_names(&array, number_of_names);
    printf("%s | %s\n", array[1], array[0]);
    return 0;
}

void add_names(char*** array, int number_of_names) {
    char *string;
    *array = malloc(sizeof(char*)*number_of_names);

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_names; i++) {
        scanf("%ms", &string);
        *array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(string) + 1);
        strcpy(*array[i], string);
    }

    printf("%s | %s\n", *array[0], *array[1]);
}
```

That doesn't even work with 2 as input. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First refactor your code to remove the `char ***`. It should never be necessary to use a triple pointer.

Comment: You use `malloc` followed by `strcpy`. Just use `strdup` instead.

Comment: Regarding: `*array[i]`  This has a precedence problem.  suggest using:`(*array)[i]`